# How would I evaluate $y=e^{2\frac{\ln2}{3}}+e^{-\frac{\ln2}{3}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$$y=e^{2\frac{\ln2}{3}}+e^{-\frac{\ln2}{3}}$$

I am not sure how I would go about evaluating this. I have tried rewriting the expression by splitting up the $e$ and the exponents but it just seemed to make it harder. The answer in the book is a number without $e$, the book did not have the steps in the solution manual so I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$e^{\ln{2}} = 2$$

Use the relation $a^{b c} = (a^{b})^{c}$, where $a=e$, $b=\ln{2}$, and $c=2/3$ or $-1/3$, so that

$$y=2^{2/3} + 2^{-1/3} = 2^{-1/3} (2 + 1) = 3 \cdot 2^{-1/3}$$