# Simplifying $y=2^{2/3} + 2^{-1/3}$

Tags: calculus, exponentiation

I am working on a calculus problem where I have to find the local minimum. The value I got was $$y=2^{2/3} + 2^{-1/3}.$$ I simplified it and got this:

$$ y=2^{2/3} + \frac{1}{2^{1/3}}$$
$$y=\frac{2^{2/3}2^{1/3}}{2^{1/3}} + \frac{1}{2^{1/3}}\frac{2+1}{2^{1/3}}=\frac{3}{2^{1/3}}$$

According to the online homework and Wolfram Alpha, the correct answer is :
$$\frac{3}{2^{2/3}}$$
Did I miss a step while simplifying the answer? I don't understand why it is $2/3$ instead of $1/3$.

Comment: The simplification is indeed correct, so maybe you made a mistake somewhere finding the local minimun.

Comment: I assume that this problem is related to this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373104/how-would-i-evaluate-y-e2-frac-ln23e-frac-ln23 Perhaps you should offer the full problem as a question instead.

Comment: Yes, that is a related problem. I will consider posting up the entire problem after I take another look at it.

Comment: I typed `2^(2/3)+2^(-1/3)` into W|A and it spat out $\displaystyle\large\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your simplification is entirely correct.  Using your original evaluation of $y$, $$y=e^{2\frac{\ln2}{3}}+e^{-\frac{\ln2}{3}}=2^{2/3} + 2^{-1/3} = \dfrac{3}{2^{1/3}}$$

Are you sure your value for $y$ is a correct mimimum?

EDIT:

Original function: $$y(x)=e^{2x}+e^{-x}$$

Critical point (minimum) at $x = \dfrac{-\ln 2}{3} \implies$

$$y=e^{-2\frac{\ln2}{3}}+e^{\frac{\ln2}{3}}=2^{-2/3} + 2^{1/3} = \dfrac{3}{2^{2/3}}$$

Comment: @amWhy The original $y(x)=e^{2x}+e^{-x}$ and I had to find the local minimum. *edit, I think I have found my error, I evaluated the positive value for the critical point when it should of been negative.

Comment: That will do it...yes, your critical point seems to be $x = \dfrac{-\ln 2}{3}$